# Spring Cloud Data Flow server unregister all apps on restart

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am able to setup spring cloud data flow server on my local machine. I have setup basic kafka based SCDF server setup by following the link as below:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#quick-start

Now when I bulk import out-of-the-box applications from the shell, it can be displayed on app list command. But when I stop the SCDF server and restart it later then all the registered/imported apps diappear the system give me the following message on app list command.

No registered apps.
You can register new apps with the 'app register' and 'app import' commands.

Is is possible that my apps remain registered even after restart of SCDF server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the local server, which is not intended for production use. The local server uses an embedded database by default, which means that, by default, data such as apps and stream definitions is also not persistent.

You can make it persistent though by configuring an external database, as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-rdbms

Comment: @alihur: Please note that the `local-server` is _still_ only recommended for development use. :)